# How to Tell Activity Monitor to Measure in GB instead of GiB?

Tags: files, process

I use the Activity Monitor application a lot, and I frequently need to know how much memory an application is using. Is there a way to tell the activity monitor to measure in GB instead of GiB?

Here's a screenshot showing the activity monitor. See how it measures memory in GiB and MiB instead of GB and MB? Can I change this by editing a config file or even code?

[image]

Comment: Eh GiB is the actual memory used so your question is a bit incorrect. GB is a marketing trick: a 1TB hard drive will be reported by the OS as 931 GiB. Divide by 0.931323 to get GB ;-) and no I doubt we can change this through a setting or config.

Comment: @Rinzwind This is Linux which means everything is open source, which means all code is accessible, which means I should be able to edit it or somehow change it. I am used to the GB unit and just because a lot of OS programs use GiB I would like to convert. Just because 1TB is also 931 GiB but just CONVERTED doesn't mean that GB is "incorrect"